# Proxy Issue with My windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have One windows server 2008. Which is not allowing any proxy request.
Even I have set proxy in browser. But it's not even allow to open any url using that proxy.
These proxies are in working condition. I have checked with my local system, May be firewall not processing this request.

Please suggest me that what can i do to solve this issue.

Thanks
Pankaj Mishra

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling windows firewall on the server? Can you ping (Or otherwise confirm connectivity) the proxy from the machine?

What error message do you get from Internet Explorer?